# How to get real-time data for Fama-French model?

Tags: pricing, factor-models, index

For Fama-French model we need `SMB` (small[market cap] minus big) and `HML` (high[book-to-market-ratio] minis low). I want to calculate daily alpha in real time, but the problem is how to get these values.

**Is there any benchmark for this values or I have to know entire market and calculate these values manually?**

Does Bloomberg or some other service provide this kind of data?

Answer (score 3):

All the Fama-French data is downloadable here:

http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html

and in particular, daily RMRF, SMB and HML data can be downloaded here:

http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/F-F_Research_Data_Factors_daily.zip

Comment: This is historical daily data which can be used for research purpose. But how to get (or how to calculate) real time data for `SMB` and `HML`. E.g. I need up to today values in order to calculate alpha for tomorrow.

Comment: The explicit way Fama and French construct SMB and HML are explained here: http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/f-f_factors.html

Basically, what they do is divide the world up a grid of 5x5 portfolios: size on one axis, value on the other. If you have access to market cap and B/E you could follow their procedure that they outline.

Hence, these factors are themselves average returns, so their calculation is dependent on the stocks you choose to input.

Comment: I have access to market cap for every company through API. As far as I understand, I need to create portfolios of small caps and big caps, so I need to download market caps for every company in order to create these portfolios, and this would be to much data for download. I am interested in some approximate values of `SMB` and `HML` to avoid this computation. **Is there any market index which is good representative of these portfolios?**

Comment: @Petar do you have an answer to this question yet? I find it very interesting. I have been thinking and searching but I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: No, I am still looking for the answer. I have implemented CAPM model which works in real time, and I want change it with Fama French but I didn't found SMB and HML data yet. It is so unusual to me that this model is well known and that we do not have these values provided by some service in real time. This rise the question if anyone uses FF, or it is just for research purpose.

Comment: @Petar I agree with you. Have you found what you were looking for yet? Something I've come across in a book just now: the IVE and IVW ETFs represent the S&P 500 Value and S&P 500 Growth respectively. I wonder if the spread could represent HML?

Comment: @Dejan I've found this: https://www.quantopian.com/posts/computing-the-fama-french-factors-with-pipeline-1

Answer (score 1):

K. French's data library gets updated with a 1-2 month delay.

Alternatives that come close are:

- Mkt-RF: [Dow Jones U.S. Total Stock Market Index](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/equity/dow-jones-us-total-stock-market-index/#overview) minus [S&P U.S. Treasury Bill 0-3 Month Index](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/fixed-income/sp-us-treasury-bill-0-3-month-index/#overview)
- SMB: [Dow Jones U.S. Thematic Market Neutral Size Index](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/strategy/dow-jones-us-thematic-market-neutral-size-index/#overview)
- HML: [Dow Jones U.S. Thematic Market Neutral Value Index](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/strategy/dow-jones-us-thematic-market-neutral-value-index/#overview)

It's important that we use market-neutral indices to replace the factors. A value or large-cap index or ETF would not do the trick, as these only cover the long side.

Comment: but the whole idea is to beat the market using F-F theory. I agree that indices provide neutral picture but that is what is captured when excess return is calculated.